# How to clone displays with my laptop and an external HD Monitor

Tags: unity, display

I have been trying to connect my laptop to an external monitor (different resolutions). My idea was to setup the external monitor as a clone of the laptop screen.

In Ubuntu Quantal's display settings I can detect both displays but I can only setup as an expanded dual monitor.

The mirror option is visible but disabled.

Is there a way to "enable" mirror mode?

Edit: In answer to ubunchu I'll try to be clearer. I merely want both displays to show the exact same image. I assume that the mirror option would do this but it is disabled.

Comment: This should be do-able, but may be a bug.  (I've had similar problems.) If you can't fix by clicking around, unfortunately you may need to go with xrandr (much more labor-intensive) as @ubunchu says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I managed to find the solution.

The mirror displays option will only be available if both monitors are set to use the same resolution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood the question well, but to change the view modes for the screen, you can use xrandr. With that you can flip the screen, invert the output (upside down, mirrored), etc. (and it also handles dual screens? maybe?)
Good luck!

Comment: Can you add any more info on typical xrandr commands+args you would use? thanks.